# Problema al integrar sdk nativo de android en react native

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

Estoy integrando un sdk nativo llamado CI360 en una aplicación React Native y estoy teniendo problemas cuando buildeo un apk en modo release.

Cuando levanto la app de forma local o creo un apk en modo debug todo funciona perfecto, todas las dependencias del sdk están incluidas, pero cuando creo un apk en modo release hay muchas dependencias del sdk que no se incluyen en su totalidad, y no estoy seguro porqué. Específicamente lo que falta en el apk release es una clase llamada SASCollector que permite inicializar el SDK.

Básicamente la integración del SDK consiste en agregar dos archivos en el proyecto. Uno se llama SASCollector.jar que va en la ruta `android/app/libs`, y otro se llama SASCollector.properties que va en el path: `android/app/src/main/assets`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que se agregan esos dos archivos se crea el módulo nativo que permite llamar las funciones java desde código javascript de la manera usual.

Ahora procedo a mostrar dos capturas de pantalla con el contenido del apk release y el apk debug.

Apk en modo debug:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apk en modo release:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en el apk release faltan muchos archivos en comparación con el apk debug, especialmente la clase SASCollector. Creo que podría ser un problema de como está configurado el proyecto que hace que no se incluyan todas las dependencias de este SDK de la forma correcta, no lo tengo en claro.

Mis dos archivos build.gradle son:

`android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
apply from: "../node_modules/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/files/plugin.gradle", to: buildscript
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/@notifee/react-native/android/libs"}
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply from: "../node_modules/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/files/dynatrace.gradle"
```

`android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))


def keysPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keys.properties")
def keysProperties = new Properties()
keysProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keysPropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.services.crunch.ar"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 412110699
        versionName "12.0.18"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MiCrunch-$versionName")
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if(keystorePropertiesFile.exists()){
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD']
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD']
                enableV3Signing = true
                // v1SigningEnabled false
            }
        }
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
       
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            zipAlignEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        production {
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "false"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID'])        
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        f5 {
            applicationIdSuffix '.f5'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "false"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        certification {
            applicationIdSuffix '.certification'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"            
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "false"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        hotfix {
            applicationIdSuffix '.hotfix'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "true"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        bugfix {
            applicationIdSuffix '.bugfix'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "true"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        integration {
            applicationIdSuffix '.integration'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "true"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
        local {
            applicationIdSuffix '.local'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.services.crunch.ar"
            buildConfigField("String", "SWRVE_API_KEY", keysProperties['SWRVE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("int", "SWRVE_APP_ID", keysProperties['SWRVE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEBUGGABLE", "false"
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_APP_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_API_KEY", keysProperties['FIREBASE_API_KEY_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_SENDER_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_SENDER_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET", keysProperties['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID", keysProperties['FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_CERT'])
            buildConfigField("String", "AES_SECRET_KEY", keysProperties['AES_SECRET_KEY'])
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", keysProperties['IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED'])
        }
  }


    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve-firebase:10.8.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")
    
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar", "*.aar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
    
    // Add the following if you are using the Adjust SDK inside web views on your app
    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android-webbridge:4.28.2'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.1'

    // Libreria para IVR
    //implementation(name: 'DialMyAppLib-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation files('libs/DialMyAppLib-release.aar')
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.10.6' 
    implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' 
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0' 
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' 
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'

    //CI360
    implementation files('libs/SASCollector.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Mi package.json es:

```
{
    "name": "CrunchApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "run-android": "react-native run-android",
        "config-debug": "rm src/redux/store.ts && cat src/redux/store-debug.ts >> src/redux/store.ts",
        "config-release": "rm src/redux/store.ts && cat src/redux/store-release.ts >> src/redux/store.ts",
        "config-dynatrace": "cp android/dynatrace.gradle node_modules/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/files",
        "android": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js integration && yarn run-android --variant=integrationDebug --appIdSuffix=integration",
        "android:cert": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js certification && yarn run-android --variant=certificationDebug --appIdSuffix=certification",
        "android:bugfix": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js bugfix && yarn run-android --variant=bugfixDebug --appIdSuffix=bugfix",
        "android:hotfix": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js hotfix && yarn run-android --variant=hotfixDebug --appIdSuffix=hotfix",
        "android:f5": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js f5 && yarn run-android --variant=f5Debug --appIdSuffix=f5",
        "android:prod": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js production && yarn run-android --variant=productionDebug",
        "android:local": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js local && yarn run-android --variant=localDebug --appIdSuffix=local",
        "pre-create-apk": "rm -rf node_modules && npm install && yarn config-dynatrace && yarn android:clean",
        "create-apk": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js integration && cd android && ./gradlew assembleIntegrationRelease",
        "create-apk:cert": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js certification && cd android && ./gradlew assembleCertificationRelease",
        "create-apk:bugfix": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js bugfix && cd android && ./gradlew assembleBugfixRelease",
        "create-apk:hotfix": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js hotfix && cd android && ./gradlew assembleHotfixRelease",
        "create-apk:f5": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js f5 && cd android && ./gradlew assembleF5Release",
        "create-apk:prod": "yarn config-release && yarn pre-create-apk && node scripts/set-environment.js production && cd android && ./gradlew assembleProductionRelease",
        "create-apk:local": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js local && cd android && ./gradlew assembleLocalRelease",
        "run-ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "ios": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js integration && yarn run-ios CrunchAppIntegration --configuration Integration.Debug",
        "ios:cert": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js certification && yarn run-ios CrunchAppCertification --configuration Beta.Debug",
        "ios:f5": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js f5 && yarn run-ios CrunchApp --configuration Production.Debug",
        "ios:prod": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js production && yarn run-ios CrunchApp --configuration Production.Debug",
        "ios:local": "yarn config-debug && node scripts/set-environment.js local && yarn run-ios CrunchAppIntegration --configuration Integration.Debug",
        "pre-create-ipa": "rm -rf node_modules && npm install",
        "create-ipa": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js integration && npm install && cd ios && pod install && node ../scripts/instructions-build-ipa.js && open CrunchApp.xcworkspace && cd ..",
        "create-ipa:cert": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js certification && npm install && cd ios && pod install && node ../scripts/instructions-build-ipa.js && open CrunchApp.xcworkspace && cd ..",
        "create-ipa:bugfix": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js bugfix && npm install && cd ios && pod install && node ../scripts/instructions-build-ipa.js && open CrunchApp.xcworkspace && cd ..",
        "create-ipa:hotfix": "yarn config-release && node scripts/set-environment.js hotfix && npm install && cd ios && pod install && node ../scripts/instructions-build-ipa.js && open CrunchApp.xcworkspace && cd ..",
        "create-ipa:prod": "yarn config-release && yarn pre-create-ipa && node scripts/set-environment.js production && cd ios && pod install && node ../scripts/instructions-build-ipa.js && open CrunchApp.xcworkspace && cd ..",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest --passWithNoTests --coverage",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --fix",
        "docs": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.config.json",
        "android:clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
        "clean:android": "cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
        "clean:ios": "rm -rf ios/build",
        "clean": "run-p clean:*",
        "build:ios_": "react-native bundle --platform ios ...",
        "build:ios": "yarn env:dev && yarn build:ios_",
        "build:ios:cert": "yarn env:cert && yarn build:ios_",
        "build:ios:prod": "yarn env:prod && yarn _build:ios",
        "instrumentDynatrace": "node node_modules/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/scripts/instrument.js"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.{ts, tsx}": [
            "eslint --fix --max-warnings=10",
            "npm run test"
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@dynatrace/react-native-plugin": "^2.243.0",
        "@notifee/react-native": "^4.1.0",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
        "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.2.1",
        "@react-native-community/react-native-cookies": "^1.1.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.7",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.5",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.9",
        "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^9.0.10",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
        "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.17",
        "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.17",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
        "@shopify/restyle": "^1.3.0",
        "@types/clone": "^2.1.1",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
        "axios": "^0.20.0",
        "better-docs": "^2.3.2",
        "clone": "^2.1.2",
        "compare-versions": "^3.6.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.64.4",
        "react-native-adjust": "^4.29.6",
        "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
        "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-bootsplash": "^2.2.7",
        "react-native-cache": "^2.0.2",
        "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.4",
        "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.4",
        "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
        "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
        "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
        "react-native-gesture-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.9",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.0",
        "react-native-image-helper": "0.0.3",
        "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
        "react-native-offline": "^5.8.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
        "react-native-redash": "^15.4.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
        "react-native-share": "^7.6.2",
        "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-store-review": "0.2.1",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.4.1",
        "react-native-swrve-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "react-native-system-setting": "^1.7.6",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.4.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
        "rn-open-especifics-settings": "^2.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
        "@redux-saga/types": "^1.1.0",
        "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
        "@types/enzyme": "3.10.7",
        "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.6",
        "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.63.64",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
        "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
        "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
        "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0",
        "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
        "reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.3",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "17.0.2",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ]
    }
}
```

En la app tengo otra librería nativa para android que se llama DialMyApp (IVR) cuya configuración en la app es muy similar a la que mencioné previamente (CI360 de SAS). Con esta librería no tengo ningún inconveniente, se incluyen todas sus dependencias en el apk en modo release.

Además pude comprobar que la integración de este sdk solo me da problemas en este proyecto en particular. Probé en integrar el sdk en otro proyecto react native y no tuve ningún inconveniente con las dependencias en el apk en modo release.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Como pueden ver en el apk release faltan muchos archivos en
> comparación con el apk debug, especialmente la clase SASCollector.

Puedes deshabilitar las opciones para optimización:

```
   release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        //minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        minifyEnabled false
        //shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        shrinkResources false

        zipAlignEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
```

o definiendo en tu archivo proguard-android.txt ("proguard-rules.pro") las clases que no deseas sean optimizadas de tu app:

```
-keep class <paquete de app>.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolver el problema anterior. Lo que sucedía era por un tema de optimización de archivos cuando se genera un apk en modo release.
Cuando se compila un apk en modo release, el compilador de android utiliza la opción de optimización ProGuard para reducir el tamaño del apk, eliminando código no utilizado y renombrando métodos y clases.
Para evitar que ProGuard nos elimine archivos durante el proceso de optimización, podemos agregar la clase o los elementos que deseamos conservar en el archivo `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`. En este último agregando:

```
-keep class com.sas.mkt.mobile.sdk.** { *; }
```

Me solucionó el problema.